# How to provide Share content functionality with discord in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, django, discord.js, discord.py

I am building an application using Python & Django in which I want to provide feature to share an event on discord. So what I want is a user can click on `share with discord` icon and get redirected to sign-in page where once he sign-in can be able to post the Event picture and it's details.

I tried to create an application with Discord and followed some tutorial but they eventually end-up with sending messages using Hooks. I want user to share content like we do in Facebook and Twitter. Is that possible to do so with Discord?

Comment: Do you mean being able to share to discord as in one would do within the android/ios app? I do not think this is available natively, but you should be able create something using discord.py